# python Tkinter calling class methods from button press

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I am using Tkinter to create a GUI. I have a class for setting up all my GUI elements and another class that does some functionality.

```
class class_one():

    def method_one(self):
        do_something()

class GUI()

    def __init__(self):
        button = Button(self, text="button", command=call_class_one_method)
        button.pack()

    def call_class_one_method(self):
         c = class_one()
         c.method_one()
```

Is this above code the correct way for calling other class methods or should I be instantiating the class in the GUI's `__init__` method? Or perhaps something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this specific case you should instantiate it in `GUI.__init__` unless there's a reason you need to create a new instance every time they click the button.

```
class GUI()

    def __init__(self):
        self.class_one = class_one()
        button = Button(self, text="button", command=self.class_one.method_one)
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you actually need a new instance of the class for every button press (which doesn't seem to be the case in your example), you should instantiate it in **init**.